# Nmap "adjust_timeouts2" error

Tags: nmap, vulnerability-scanners, ports, network-scanners, error-handling

Just tried a port scan against a cloudflare protected website:

```
nmap -sV --version-intensity 9 --top-ports 2500 -v --script banner --data-length 0 -n <ip address here> -Pn -T2 -sT
```

I get a lot of this as a result:

> adjust_timeouts2: packet supposedly had rtt of 125995326 microseconds.  Ignoring time.

- How is "adjust_timeouts2" effecting my scan and why?
- What is rtt?
- What does "Ignoring time." mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Your message should come from the `-T` option level set from 0 to  5. The option is the temporize between the in/out going of the IP packets. The 5 is last number and the quicker, and you put 2.

RTT is meaning the round trip  times  is also known as the ping time. You could use `--min_rtt_timeout/max-rtt-timeout/initial-rtt-timeout <msec>` option and many other found in the man page of nmap

Ignoring time in you case should mean the time is to long to be evaluate. 125 second is an eternity in network.